# Pandas read html only returning 1 table when 5 tables r found

Tags: python, selenium, pandas

I am trying to use selenium to scrape tables off the weblink below. However, pandas seems to only be returning the first table, and not all tables.

```
weblink = 'http://sgx.com/wps/portal/sgxweb/home/company_disclosure/stockfacts?page=2&code=A68U&lang=en-us'
path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
driver.get(weblink)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 8)
# locate and switch to the iframe
iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mainContent iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'financials')))  # Should I be using this?

print(pandas.read_html(driver.page_source, flavor='bs4'))
```

How can I get pandas to print out all tables instead of just the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the content of the `TABLE` that was returned? It actually contains all 5 "tables". What looks like separate `TABLE` tags on the page is actually just one and 5 `TBODY`s formatted to look like separate `TABLE`s. You should familiarize yourself with the browser's dev console. I would recommend Chrome's. Right click on an element inside the table and choose Inspect from the context menu. Now hover over the elements in the dev console and the browser will highlight the element on the webpage. This is a good way to correlate elements in the HTML with elements on the page. If you do this on this page, you will see that there is only one `TABLE` tag and each `TBODY` looks like a separate `TABLE`.

Comment: Hmm, I see it now when I was inspecting the html tags. But how can I draw out the `tbody`s with Selenium / Pandas?

Comment: Same way you do with any element... I don't guess I understand what you are asking?

Comment: What I meant was, I tried to search for `tbody`s and feed that into `pandas` but I still cant draw out all 5 "tables". How should I be coding it to extract them?

Comment: I don't know anything about `pandas` but your problem wasn't related to it, it's related to how you were looking at the HTML. This seems like a pretty basic question that has likely been answered on this site or elsewhere. Have you googled it? What did you find?